# How can I solve this problem using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm stuck in this problem and I would need some help:

Given an array `arr`, in each step, 1, 2 or 5 units have to be incremented **to all but one item of the array**. The goal is to find the minimum number of steps to all items to be equal.

**First example**

`arr = [1, 1, 5]`

```
1) [1 (+2), 1 (+2), 5] = [3, 3, 5]
2) [3 (+2), 3 (+2), 5] = [5, 5, 5]
```

Solution: 2 steps

---

**Second example**

`arr = [2, 2, 3, 7]`

```
1) [2 (+1), 2 (+1), 3, 7 (+1)] = [3, 3, 3, 8]
2) [3 (+5), 3 (+5), 3 (+5), 8] = [8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Solution: 2 steps

---

I have tried some things but I'm really stuck.

I consider a base case when all items are already equal. In another case, I try to find all the possible solutions by incrementing 1, 2 and 5 to every item but one in the array:

```
def equal(arr):

    if (allElementsIdentical(arr)):
        return 0

    min = sys.maxsize
    for i in [1, 2, 5]:
        for j in range(len(arr)):

            #Increment all items by "i", except item at index "j"
            newArr = arr.copy()
            for k in range(j):
                newArr[k] += i
            for k in range(j + 1, len(newArr)):
                newArr[k] += i

            movements = 1 + equal(newArr)
            if movements < min:
                min = movements
    return min
```

This solution doesn't work because recursion never ends. E.g.

```
[1, 1, 5] -> [1, 2, 6] -> [1, 3, 7] -> [1, 4, 8] -> [1, 5, 9] -> ...
```

Is it my initial approach correct? How can I break it down in subproblems?

Comment: Here's a hint: The final values don't matter, only the fact that they are equal. Think of what happens in terms of the relative differences of the elements in the array. Adding $i$ to all but one elements is equivalent to to decreasing $i$ from exactly one element -- the one you wouldn't add to. For example, in the first case your solution is equivalent to subtracting twice 2 from 5 to obtain [1,1,1].

Comment: Thank you, you are right. In the second case, subtracting 1 from 3 and 5 from 7, you obtain [2, 2, 2, 2] in two steps. I'm going to try to code it.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is as in the answer by @izanbf1803.

However, there is a detail: after you find the minimum value `m`, you should go through the array again, keeping in mind that `m`, `m - 1` and `m - 2` could all be your final target. After getting the total number of steps for all three of them, just return the smallest one.

For example, if the array is `[0, 0, 0]`, then the best final target is `m = 0`;

if the array is `[1, 5, 5]`, then the best final target is `m - 1 = 0`;

if the array is `[2, 5, 5]`, then the best final target is `m - 2 = 0`.

---

But why only these three possibilities? The reason is as follows.

Let `f(n)` be the number of steps required to decrease a number by `n`. It's easy to show by induction that:

- `f(5k) = k`
- `f(5k + 1) = k + 1`
- `f(5k + 2) = k + 1`
- `f(5k + 3) = k + 2`
- `f(5k + 4) = k + 2`

and to continue:

- `f(5k + 5) = k + 1`
- `f(5k + 6) = k + 2`
- `f(5k + 7) = k + 2`
- etc.

from which one sees that `f(n) <= f(n + 3)`.

If a number `t` is chosen as the final target, then the total minimum number of steps is just the sum of `f(x - t)` for all `x` in the array. Hence choosing any number `t <= m - 3` as final target would be pointless, since `t + 3` would be a better choice.

Thus the final algorithm goes like this:

---

Input: array `arr`

Output: minimum number of steps to make all numbers equal

```
Define a constant array c = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2].
Let m = minimum value in the array arr.
Let s = 0, s1 = 0 and s2 = 0.
For every element x in arr:
    Let y = x - m, y1 = y + 1 and y2 = y + 2
    Add [y / 5] + c[y mod 5] to s.
    Add [y1 / 5] + c[y1 mod 5] to s1.
    Add [y2 / 5] + c[y2 mod 5] to s2.
End For.
Return min(s, s1, s2).
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing all elements but one is equivalent to decrease only that element. Find minimum value `m`, now for each element `x` you need to find minumum number of subtractions to go from `x` to `m` (change-making problem), since you can use greedy algorithm for coins `(1, 2, 5)`, you can solve this problem in O(n).

Comment: This will not always give the correct answer. Say the original array is `[1, 5, 5]`. Your algorithm would return `4` by decreasing the two `5` to `1`. But one can actually do in `3` steps: decrease all of them to `0`.